# Does ARINC 825 (Aviation CAN bus) follow the same protocol as automotive CAN buses?

Tags: avionics

From what I can gather it is derived from the automotive industry standard CAN (Controller Area Network) bus, but I was wondering if they share the same protocols. If you took an automotive bus reader and hooked it up to a ARINC 825 system would it read the same?

Comment: It would be able to determine IDs of responding devices but likely not much functional or useful information as ARINC also defines an application layer protocol, there is rarely in the wild "naked can" implementations, CAN on its own does not really define semantic meaning of data transfered back and forth by the CAN bus. Your automotive reader supports automotive applications, if one is similiar enough to arinc you might get intelligible data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the underlying CAN protocol is the same.  The 825 standard specifies some CAN IDs/priority scheme for standard purposes, similar to the ARINC429 label standard.  It also specifies certain CAN bit timing configuration, such as 1 sample per bit at 75% of the bit time, and re-synchronization jump width at 1 time quanta.  These are all settings in the CAN standard.

This datasheet provides some hints, but unfortunately being an ARINC standard there isn't much public information about the label and data structures.

[Holt HI-3110 ARINC 825 compatible transceiver](http://www.holtic.com/documents/371-hi-3110_v-rev-kpdf.do)

If you connect a CANBus tool that supports extended ID's you should be able to see the CAN data.  The bus is comparable at a CANbus and electrical level.